# Loading MBTiles file using GeoTools?

Tags: geotools, mbtiles

is there a way to load MBTiles file using GeoTools?

I need to work with huge map and so far I have tried PNG + world file which was unusable (slow speed due to large files - 150MB). So I am thinking about using some sort of database and loading it by tiles would be the best way. I can easily create MBTiles (using MOBAC).

I have found MBTiles class in documentation http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/mbtiles/mosaic/package-summary.html but there is only a little explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would check the tests in github, [here](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/unsupported/mbtiles/src/test/java/org/geotools/mbtiles/mosaic/MBTilesReaderTest.java).

That said I would say you should look into optimized (big)tiff support. 
Check these slides which are made for GeoServer but still usable for your case I believe.
http://goo.gl/74XUPq

Comment: I would like to use geotiff but MOBAC is not able to export maps in geotiff. Do you know any programs that can have mapsources like mobac but can export geotiff images? Or any tool that can convert from MOBAC formats to geotiff? ... anyway thanks for answer